# Logic behind loading dimension tables

Tags: oracle11g, data-warehouse, informatica-powercenter, dimensional-modeling

How do I populate Dim_tbls from a relational source?

These example tables are given:

```
tbl_sales:    id_sales, fk_id_customer, fk_id_product, country, timestamp   
tbl_customer: id_customer, name, adress, zip, city
tbl_product:  id_product, price, product
```

My goal is to get these attributes into a start-schema. The problem I have is the logic behind loading the dimension tables. I mean, what data would I load into the Dim_Product? All the products that are in tbl_product? But how would I know how many Sales are done with a specific product?

Analysis I would like to do are:

```
 How many people bought product x.
 How many sales are made from city x.
 How many sales were made between Time x and y.
```

---

Example data:

```
 tbl_sales: id_sales | fk_id_customer | fk_id_product | country | timestamp 
                1    |       2        |      1        |   UK    | 19.11.2013 10:23:22
                2    |       1        |      2        |   FR    | 20.11.2013 06:04:22

 tbl_customer: id_customer | name | adress | zip | city
                      1    | Frank|Street X| 211 | London
                      2    | Steve|Street Y| 431 | Paris

 tbl_customer: id_product| Price | product
                      1  | 100,00| Hammer
                      2  |  50,00| Saw
```

Comment: yes. as i said this is only an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with a very simple star schema model; for example, I assumed you don't need to worry about handling changes to dimensions' attributes.

## factSales

```
  DateKey
  CustomerKey
  ProductKey
  Counter (=1; this is a factless fact table)
```

## dimDate

```
  DateKey
  Date
  Year
  Quarter
  Month
  ...
```

## dimCustomer

```
  CustomerKey
  Name
  Address
  Zip
  City
```

## dimProduct

```
  ProductKey
  Name
  Price (if it changes, you need move it to factSales)
```

---

*How many people bought product x.*

```
SELECT DISTINCT CustomerKey
FROM factSales
WHERE ProductKey IN ( SELECT ProductKey
                      FROM dimProduct
                      WHERE Name = 'Product X' )
```

*How many sales are made from city x.*

```
SELECT SUM(Counter)
FROM factSales
WHERE CustomerKey IN ( SELECT CustomerKey
                       FROM dimCustomer
                       WHERE City = 'City X' )
```

*How many sales were made between Time x and y.*

```
SELECT SUM(Counter)
FROM factSales
WHERE DateKey IN ( SELECT DateKey
                   FROM dimDate
                   WHERE Date BETWEEN DateX AND DateY )
```

Comment: Alright, so far I understand it. But how would I load the tables from my example above (see end of edited post). I don't get how we split the data into the dim / fact tables. For example the date .. ok I got dated in the Dim table now but how does the schema know when the sale was done? And BTW: in my data model no data is going to be changed in the future.

Comment: The fact table contains a reference to `dimDate` (column `DateKey`), so you need to join these two tables to determine the date of sale. Your example is pretty simple, so there is a 1:1 mapping of transactional tables and dimensional ones + `dimDate` that should be pre-populated with all dates from the period you are interested in. You start with the dimensions - load the attributes from your tables (including natural keys) and generate surrogate keys (`CustomerKey`, `ProductKey`, etc). Then load the fact table - use lookups to obtain appropriate keys from the dimensions.

Comment: I highly recommend the [The Definitive Guide to Dimensional Modeling](http://www.amazon.com/The-Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Dimensional/dp/1118530802) book or at least the [core dimensional modeling techniques](http://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/).